# Listpicker unclickable

Tags: binding, listpicker

I have written a listbox to display the "Engine Size" of a set of data from an XML sheet, the item binding seems to work, and the listbox works prefectly for the first two options however the rest are completly unclickable.

I have tried breaks in the code and it is showing that clicking on one of the not working values doesnt even trigger the "ListPicker_ChangedSelection" program i have.

The code I have is below.

```
    private void Choose_Engine_Size_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        String carenginesize=((enginesize)Choose_Engine_Size.SelectedItem).Esize.ToString();
        List<enginesize> enginesize =GetCarData();
        foreach (enginesize c in enginesize)
        {
            if(c.Esize==carenginesize)
            {
                ConsumptionBox.Text=c.Consumption;
                EmmissionsBox.Text=c.Emissions;

        }
    }
```

From this is then goes to make some caluclation with the populated values from this.

My Listpicker code is as follows:

```
        <toolkit:ListPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,22,0,0" x:Name="Choose_Engine_Size" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" SelectionChanged="Choose_Engine_Size_SelectionChanged" Height="Auto" Opacity="1">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Esize}" FontSize="20" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```